# On two types of shifted symmetric power sums

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

In the ring of shifted symmetric functions $\Lambda^*$ there are many ways to generalize the symmetric power sums. First of all, we have the functions $$p^*_k=\sum_{i=1} \left((x_i-i+1/2)^k-(-i+1/2)^k\right)$$
(the factor 1/2 is convenient when the $x_i$ are the parts of a partition, but can replaced by any constant). For a partition $\kappa$ we let $p^*_\kappa=p^*_{\kappa_1}p^*_{\kappa_2}\cdots.$ Another shifted analogue to the power sums are the functions $p_\kappa^\#$, defined by
$$p^\#_\kappa = \sum_{\lambda \vdash k} \chi_\kappa^\lambda s_\lambda^*,$$
where k=$|\kappa|$ is the size of the partition $\kappa$. Both $p_\kappa^*$ and $p_\kappa^\#$ provide a basis for $\Lambda^*$. (For more details: see the original paper 'Shifted Schur Functions' by Okounkov and Olshanski or the post [On shifted symmetric power sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214551/on-shifted-symmetric-power-sums)).

In the literature there is a vast amount of results relating different bases of $\Lambda^*$ to each other. However, the only relation between the bases by $p_\kappa^*$ and $p_\kappa^\#$ I can find is that
$$p_\kappa^\#=p_\kappa^*+\textrm{lower degree terms},$$
(because the highest degree terms of $p_\kappa^\#$ and $p_\kappa^*$ equal the ordinary symmetric power sum $p_\kappa$). How can these lower degree terms be expressed in terms of $p_\kappa^*$ (or $p_\kappa^\#$)?

Question: Are there any expressions known relating $p_\kappa^*$ and $p_\kappa^\#$?

Comment: You might want to look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214551/on-shifted-symmetric-power-sums?rq=1 and see if there is something related

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, yes, I've seen this post (I even referred to it in my question). The posts indeed introduce $p_\kappa^*$ and $p_\kappa^\#$ but they are not related there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is precisely given by the Gromov-Witten/Hurwitz correspondence by Okounkov and Pandharipande (see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204305). Up to the constant $(1-2^{-k})\zeta(-k)$ the functions $p_k^*$ equal the renormalized shifted symmetric power sums $\mathbf{p}_k$ which occur in expressions of integrals of descendants classes in Gromov-Witten theory (equation 0.25). The functions $p_\kappa^\#$ equal (up to a multiplicative constant depending on $\kappa$) the central characters $\mathbf{f}_\kappa$ of the symmetric group as explained in the related post [On shifted symmetric power sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214551/on-shifted-symmetric-power-sums?rq=1). These functions occur naturally in the character formula for extended Hurwitz numbers (equation 0.10). The completion coefficients relating $\mathbf{p}_k$ and $\mathbf{f}_\kappa$ are given by equation 0.22 in the before-mentioned article.